# Close popup UITableViewController view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

How do I know when the view got closed? Am currently using the delegate pattern, capture viewDidDisappear to fire the event... Is this the correct one to use? Downside of viewDidDisappear is that when my view move to a sub-view the event still fires.

Its a custom view that i made that exptend UITableViewController... In that table you got a list of options that you manage, so when moving between those screens I don't want my event to fire.. I only want it to fire when I close the actual view.

Comment: what has the table got to do with the view closing ??

Comment: what you mean?? when your view push in new view??

Comment: Its a custom view that i made that exptend UITableViewController... In that table you got a list of options that you manage, so when moving between those screens I don't want my event to fire.. I only want it to fire when I close the actual view.

Comment: you means tableview is a subview on your main view??

Comment: yes I open up the tableview (UITableViewController) as a popup (iPad app) then from there I open up other sub-views. So when I close the tableview I want to notify the main view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now just see when your `UITableView` begin open at that time you set the bool value like...

first define this variable global in your .h file like bellow

```
BOOL isTableOpen;
```

and after that in your .m file

set yes when your tableview is open with button tap event or anything else which you used...

```
isTableOpen = YES;
```

after when your pop-up view or UITableview closed at that time set value `NO` like

```
isTableOpen = NO;
```

and check in your `viewDidDisappear:` that if `isTableOpen` is true then do nothing otherwise yes...

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    if(isTableOpen){
       //call your method which you want...
    }
}
```

i hope this help you or get some Idea ..

:)